# Matplotlib xaxis with ticks on empty dates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to display a pandas DataFrame without the built-in plot function and struggle to get only the dates of the DataFrame on the x-axis. Matplotlib on its own displays empty bins/dates which I would like to avoid.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
dates = [pd.to_datetime(x) for x in ['2023-07-27', '2023-07-28', '2023-07-31']]
data = pd.DataFrame([3,2,4], index=dates, columns=['val'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
labels = [item.get_text()[:10] for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.show()
```

This gives the following figure:
[image: pandas plot]

Trying to replicate this plot without pandas plot looks like this, but the figure has multiple empty ticks.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(data.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(data.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
ax.bar(data.index, data.val)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How to not plot the empty bins in matplotlib? The `set_xticks` approach above did not work as expected. If you comment both `ax.set_xtick*` out, you get the labeled ticks in between as well.

Edit: It can happen that there are other dataframes that will be plotted in the same graphic with other dates. The example above just showcases the gap and I would want a method that tells matplotlib to not display all the empty bins, **ideally independent from the input dataset**. Matplotlib has all the information, it should be able to delete empty bins.

```
#additional example
data2 = pd.DataFrame([1,3], index=[pd.to_datetime(x) for x in ['2023-08-01', '2023-08-02']], columns=['val2'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(data.index, data.val)
ax.bar(data2.index, data2.val2)
### add something here to delete empty bins
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

If you call `ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()` you will see that it created major ticks at positions, where no datapoint was recorded. As stated in a comment I believe this is due to the conversion of date -> integer number of days after 1970. Therefore, I would like to have the option to tell matplotlib to ignore empty bins or a function to manually remove them.

Answer (score 3):

A simple option is to not use the dates as the `xtick` positions, e.g.,:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(range(len(data)))  # just set ticks to [0, 1, 2]
ax.set_xticklabels(data.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
ax.bar(range(len(data)), data.val)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it is a bit too simple of a solution. For example, if I would want to plot another dataset in the same figure at the same times it would be a struggle.

Comment: Would your hypothetical other dataset also just have values at the same dates or different dates? If it contains different dates, then I think you'll struggle to do what you want. If it's the same dates then you'd need to apply some mapping that maps those particular dates to the particular index values.

Comment: Alternatively to my solution, you could create your dataframe without the dates being the index values, i.e., just include them as another column in the dataframe. Then you can plot the bar chart using the index (which will just be integer values) as you originally did, but set the labels using the dates column. If your other data has the same dates, then you could again just plot using the integer indices.

Comment: @FirefightingPhysicist Could you clarify the question in relation to your note about the possibility of plotting a different dataset in the same figure. This looks unrelated to the original post.

Comment: @Matt Pitkin: I was looking for a general solution. Yes, the other dataframe can have different dates, but you are correct that I would be able to merge them into a joint dataframe and use the index for the position and the date as a label.

Comment: @Vitalizzare: I will try to clarify later, but I was hoping for a matplotlib option and not a 'hack'. If there is none, I'll accept it later

Comment: I think the translation into ticks just needs to be a bit better. `ax.xaxis.majorticklocs()` looks like it just transfers the date into the integer number of days since 1970-01-01. I think I will just map those to be days since 1970-01-01 with data and I should be fine

Comment: I don't think you can "delete empty bins". You just have to replot things at manually set indexes, such that there is no additional space. This could be either by combining your dataframes (and sorting by date) or extracting and storing the bar information from each time you plot and combining it back into a new plot with the x-positions shifted as required (but this seems more hassle than just merging the original dataframes). Is there any reason you can't just merge the dataframes?